# Line graph connecting wrong points R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot this time series within R however I've noticed that there are certain points that are joined together which shouldn't be. Plotting the data alone there is no issue, so I've narrowed it down to being an issue with the date along the x-axis. I've read that its to do with ordering however everything is in the correct date order and all the data is within the same year. Here is the code and plot that I have created. Any thoughts into why this occurs? and only for specific points?

**note: my actual data set output was too big to add into here so I have only included the first and last points

Thanks!

```
JuneDO <- data.frame(MJune$Australian.Western.Standard.Time,MJune$Dissolved.Oxygen)
names(JuneDO) <- c("datetime", "DO")

> head(JuneDO)
         datetime    DO
 1 2018-06-22 11:36:00 5.482
 2 2018-06-22 11:46:00 3.595
 3 2018-06-22 11:56:00 4.124
 4 2018-06-22 12:06:00 3.902
 5 2018-06-22 12:16:00 3.824
 6 2018-06-22 12:26:00 3.601

> tail(JuneDO)
            datetime    DO
2449 2018-06-30 23:06:00 4.288
2450 2018-06-30 23:16:00 3.526
2451 2018-06-30 23:26:00 3.668
2452 2018-06-30 23:36:00 3.418
2453 2018-06-30 23:46:00 4.824
2454 2018-06-30 23:56:00 5.357

JuneDO$datetime <- as.POSIXct(JuneDO$datetime, tz="GMT", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
plot(JuneDO, type="l")
```

[image: Line graph connecting start and end point]

Comment: Do `which(diff(JuneDO$datetime, units="mins") > 10)` and see if you have one row-to-row difference that is *much* larger than all the others - then track down that row. It does look to me like something is not in order with your date.

Comment: It came up as `integer(0)` so I'm assuming the rows are okay? its super strange

Comment: Whoops, try `which(abs(diff(JuneDO$datetime, units="mins")) > 10)` - the jump is from the end to the start so you need an `abs` on there to find the big negative diff. I suspect you have a much earlier date right at the end of your data.

Comment: Ah! yes you were right, the data copied itself again, and I lost it due to the big dataset, thank you!!